# server not listening on port 5432

Tags: tomcat, localhost

My localhost is Apache Tomcat. The server is not accepting connections and I am getting error message

> connection to localhost refused

on GeoServer and PostgreSQL 9.5 on port 5432. I used the `postgresql.conf` editor that is built into `pgAdminIII` to edit the `postgresql.conf` configuration file to change the '`listen_addresses`' parameter where it was already set to "`*`" for listening to all available IP addresses.

This is the error message displayed on `PostgreSQL`:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what change did you make to `listen_addresses`?

Comment: I used  * for all IP addresses. Initially I tried  0.0.0.0 that allows listening for all IPv4 addresses and then :: that allows listening for all IPv6 addresses. It didn't work so I set it back to *.

Comment: Hmm. Unless you need to connect remotely, you should leave `listen_addresses` unset, so that it [only listens to localhost](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES).

Answer (score 0):

Try use the local IP of machine.

A similar error happen to me when i use PostgreSQL in a Docker machine, and just works when i use the local IP of machine.

Comment: Thanks but which one IPv4 or IPv6?

Comment: I always use the IPv4.

Comment: Is not working for me, tried both.